# What is the difference between proc_create_data() and register_chrdev() functions?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

Indeed, both create a special file with the corresponding `struct file_operations`. What is the difference?

I need to create a special file that exports a binary stream to the userspace. Which function should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `proc_create_data` creates a proc entry while `register_chrdev` creates a character device. What is there to compare? `create a special file that exports a binary stream` - that looks like a job for a character device, but there are many ways to do that.

Comment: Both character device and a file in `/proc` file system can be used for "exports a binary stream to the userspace". You may use any of them for your purpose.